# Is the +Cha to hit/damage from Slippers of Battledancing worth complicating my build?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, magic-items, optimization, damage, ability-scores

I am working on a build that is as Charisma reliant as possible. Literally needing nothing but Charisma and a little constitution to function.

I've been fascinated with the Slippers of Battledancing for a very long time and have tried desperately to integrate it into a build.
However the more I play around with it, the more I realize they may not be worth it.
For this build, what is most appealing is:

> If he moves at least 10 feet as part of a move action, he can use his Charisma modifier instead of his Strength or Dexterity modifier for attack rolls and damage rolls with one-handed or light weapons (both melee and ranged).

At first glance these things look amazing. But I soon realized how limiting it is, as in order to get the Charisma benefit you must move at least 10 feet as part of a move action — **move** action, which means things like travel devotion do not work as RAW.

This means that the only way to make it work is to go into the spring attack tree, which is already considered to be sub-par due to what you have to do to get in. (I considered a convoluted Pounce build, but since charging doesn't usually use a *move* action, that's out.) You can work it into a Swiftblade build, but then you have to use either Sorcerer or Bard as a base and, as good as the class is, those 4 lost caster builds are a *massive* downside.

Not to mention that, since Gauntlets of Heartfelt Blows exists, I have a cheaper option to getting +Cha to damage, albeit as fire damage.

So at the end of the day, are Slippers of Battledancing worth building around, or am I better off finding other options to get that +Cha to attack?

Answer (score 3):

Just to confirm, the typical options here don’t work: charges are no good, Travel Devotion is no good, even an attempt to use *sparring dummy of the master* for “ten-foot steps” doesn’t help.

So your options here are pretty limited. A psionic manifester could try to spam *hustle*, which gives an actual, legitimate move action, and a sublime initiator could focus on strikes for their attacks, rather than full-attacks, but neither of these things slots neatly onto a Cha-focused build. Perhaps the best option is archery, since Greater Manyshot would get you a bunch of attacks from a standard action, but the [Charming the Arrow](http://archive.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/fey/20030815a) feat partially obviates the point of the *slippers of battledancing* since it already replaces Dexterity with Charisma for bow shots.

A build based on Flyby Attack is conceivable—unlike Spring Attack, Flyby Attack lacks awful prerequisites and allows **any** standard action to take place in the middle of a move action. You miss out on Bounding Assault and Rapid Blitz from *Player’s Handbook II*, but Rapid Blitz is very difficult to take anyway (absolutely cannot miss any BAB). And instead of Bounding Assault, you can use *wolf fang strike* from *Tome of Battle* or Dual Strike from *Complete Adventurer*.

Either way, Snap Kick from *Tome of Battle* can add another attack. That’s three attacks (one specifically with an unarmed strike, or with an *aptitude* weapon). *Dancing* and *raging mongoose*, Tiger Strike maneuvers from *Tome of Battle*, could give you two or four more, respectively. In theory, *dancing mongoose* is even available to a non-initiator via Martial Study at 18th level, and it doesn’t have the absurd BAB +18 requirement that Rapid Blitz does.

So a swordsage from *Tome of Battle* could very easily use *wolf fang strike*, *dancing mongoose*, and *raging mongoose*. It also gets Wisdom-to-AC-in-light-armor, which Ascetic Mage could swap to Charisma. The unarmed adaptation even gets you Improved Unarmed Strike for both Ascetic Mage and Snap Kick. And you could use jade phoenix mage in the same book to advance whatever arcane spellcasting class—sha’ir is best—you got to meet the other half of Ascetic Mage’s prerequisites, though you’d need somewhat more levels in it before you could start jade phoenix mage.

If combined with a couple paladin levels, you get divine grace and—if you can worship Milil or ignore that requirement—inspire courage. Between those and a level in an arcane class, you have three non-initiator levels—because of the way initiator level works, that means you benefit from a fourth such level. Cleric works (Charm domain gives +4 Charisma for a minute, 1/day), particularly if cloistered (more skill points and free Knowledge Devotion, per *Complete Champion*, which is another boost to all your attacks). Scout is another interesting option, since you’ll be triggering skirmish anyway, though you won’t be able to progress it much—even with Improved Skirmish, it’s only +3d6 damage. To go the skirmish route, using moon-warded ranger instead of swordsage to get Wis-to-AC-in-light-armor and then taking Swift Hunter seems better, but then it’s difficult to get the boost maneuvers you want.

Either way, a couple levels of unseen seer are a decent way to advance your spellcasting to the point you can start taking levels in jade phoenix mage. If you take cleric, though, ruby knight vindicator becomes available and arguably better (note it requires worship of Wee Jas, which might be a problem if you’re also forced to worship Milil—*Tome of Battle* does recommend adapting the class to other gods though).

But this is building around the *slippers*. Not something you just toss on to an existing build.